# Splitting text based on comma

Tags: c#, string, csv, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSV parser/reader for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c)

I want to split the text using the `Split` function:

```
string str = "ZBEE10364,\"Cobler, CHARLOTTE J\",Whiskey,,Brandy,0:00:00,20110912,CHECK,2918,117.33,1,117.33,0,EDM0,Yu789";
string[] strArr = str.Split(',');
```

This works fine but `"Cober` and `"CHARLOTTE` are in different records. I don't want that. It is a CSV file and when I open it using Excel it works perfectly.

`Cobler, CHARLOTTE J` appears in a single column. How can I solve this?

Comment: If it's a CSV file, use a proper CSV parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Great. I eneded up using FileHelpers. Vlad you can post it as an asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helper method does the trick:

```
public static class StringSplitHelper{

  public static string[] SplitNonQuoted(this string str, char separator){
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return new string[]{};
    if(separator == '\"') throw new ArgumentException("Separator cannot be a quotation mark", "separator"); 
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    bool inQuotes = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var c in str){
        if(c == '\"')
        {
            inQuotes = !inQuotes;
        }
        else if(c == separator){
            if(inQuotes) {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            else {
                fields.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
            }
        }
        else{
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return fields.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Then, instead of `strArr = str.Split(',');`, 
do `strArr = str.SplitNonQuoted(this string str, ',');`

Comment: @Jaggu, The source in the post that Hogan linked to has **a better generic solution** for parsing CSV files.  (although it doesn't let you use a `Split` method)

Answer (score 3):

Because you want to ignore `,` in records that are between quotes, the only way to do this is to parse the line.

Loop over the string with a boolean (true if between quotes) and then hand build the list/array only making a new item when the boolean is false.

As Andreas points out in the comments there is complete source located in this question:

[Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 2):

Might be overkill, but the OLE DB provider for JET can also read CSV files, and can also give you data of the proper types for each column. Example use in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865373/importing-csv-handling-dates).

If you want to parse it by hand (which should be doable), you can refer to the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules) on CSV, which details the syntax a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO; //Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
using System.IO;

public class Sample {
    static void Main(){
        string str = "ZBEE10364,\"Cobler, CHARLOTTE J\",Whiskey,,Brandy,0:00:00,20110912,CHECK,2918,117.33,1,117.33,0,EDM0,Yu789";
        string[] strArr = str.Split(',');
        var reader = new StringReader(str);
        using(var csvReader = new TextFieldParser(reader)){
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] {","});
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            strArr = csvReader.ReadFields();
        }

        //check print
        foreach(var item in strArr){
            Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"",item);
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
"ZBEE10364"
"Cobler, CHARLOTTE J"
"Whiskey"
""
"Brandy"
"0:00:00"
"20110912"
"CHECK"
"2918"
"117.33"
"1"
"117.33"
"0"
"EDM0"
"Yu789"
```